# Fetching v2 rendezvous descriptor failed. Retrying at another directory

Tags: onion-services, ubuntu

My system tor version 0.2.9.10 (on Ubuntu 16.04) is outputing a lot of the following warnings:

> Fetching v2 rendezvous descriptor failed. Retrying at another directory.

Is there some way to fix it? Perhaps there's a way to force tor to fetch the descriptors?

Answer (score 3):

Your version of Tor has bug which causes this messages (see [#21056](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/21056)). Version 0.3.0.6 has a [partial fix](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tor-0306-released-new-series-stable). If you install this version there are high chances that the messages will go away. Currently the developers are working on a full fix (see [#17242](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/17242)).

So I would recommend to install a newer version. Please follow the advise at [the instruction page for Debian and Ubuntu](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en) and add the following line to your `sources.list` file:

```
deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org tor-experimental-0.3.0.x-xenial main
```

After you updated the repositories you can choose to install the newest version.

Comment: I'd prefer to wait a bit until tor 0.3.0.6 is stable and I don't have to edit my `sources.list`. Otherwise it's great advice, thanks!

Comment: Ok, I've upgraded to tor 0.3.0.7, and the problem persists.

Comment: Same issue, Tor 0.3.2.8-rc (git-3696eb720795a666) on Raspberry Pi. Also getting a lot of `Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to phgry32xorhxerfc:4003. Giving up. (waiting for rendezvous desc)` and `Giving up. (waiting for circuit)` messages in the log

Comment: Issue still persists for Tor version 0.3.3.7